# How to add autocomplete for path to custom completion function in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I created my own zsh completion function for `audtool`. Here's a sample:-

```
#compdef audtool

_audtool() { 
    local state

_arguments \
    '1: :->csi'\

case $state in
csi)
    _arguments '1::(
    --current-song
    --current-song-filename 
    --help
    --playlist-addurl)'
;;
esac
}

_audtool "$@"
```

The above function runs just fine except for one small glitch i.e., after the autocomplete when I try to add a path to a file the path doesn't expand. What I want to ask is that why doesn't

```
audtool --playlist-addurl /h
```

expand to

```
audtool --playlist-addurl /home/
```

after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If anybody can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. To add an argument such that it displays full path all I had to do is add these lines:

```
_arguments '*:filename:_files'
```

So, the final function looks like:

```
#compdef audtool

_audtool() { 
    local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
    typeset -A opt_args

    _arguments \
        '1: :->csi'\
        '2: :->file'

    case $state in
    csi)
        _arguments '1: :(
            --current-song
            --current-song-filename 
            --current-song-length
            --playlist-addurl)'
    ;;
    file)
        _arguments '*:filename:_files'
    ;;
    esac
}

_audtool "$@"
```